# Variable specific to turtle and patch

Tags: netlogo

In NetLogo, I can create turtle-specific variables with turtles-own, and patch-specific variables with patches-own. But how can I create variables that are specific to a turtle AND a patch?

Specifically, I want to create a preference function - each turtle has a preference to live in a certain patch. The preferences are different for each turtle and patch, for example, turtle 1 has preference 20 to live in patch (1,1) and preference 30 to live in patch (2,2), etc. How can I define this function in NetLogo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to have a unique mapping between each turtle and each patch. My first thought is to use the built-in matrix extension via

```
extensions [matrix]
```

and have a turtles-own variable "preferences" that is a matrix with the dimensions of your world (e.g. if max-pxcor and max-pycor are both 16 and your origin is centered, you need a 33x33 matrix).

Each element of "preferences" then corresponds to one patch and denotes the assigned value.

See the NetLogo User Manual for documentation on how to fill the matrix with values.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.